# Query battery information in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

I want to query battery information on a Linux system **without** using `/proc` or `/sys`.

I have done some research and found out about [power_supply.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/include/linux/power_supply.h). The header seems to contain the required information, but I'm not sure what to do.

How could I query the information in ex. `POWER_SUPPLY_PROP_CURRENT_NOW`?

**EDIT:**

I want to avoid using third party libraries like `libupower-glib` and only use what is available directly in the Linux kernel.

Comment: You need to read about *libudev*.

Comment: what is wrong with querying `/proc`? you may be interested in [UPower](https://upower.freedesktop.org/)

Comment: @bansi on hardened Linux systems `/proc` and `/sys` are usually only readable by root. I also want to avoid using third party libraries.

Comment: What's your definition of a _third party library_? And please include the restrictions in the question.

Comment: @MartinZabel My definition of a third party library is anything that is not available in the kernel sources.

Comment: "anything that is not available in the kernel sources". You must then code directly in binary code, as there are bi compilers, assemblers or runtime libraries in there.

Comment: If battery monitors are enabled, then info can be found in /sys/class/power_supply. If you are working with an embedded device, then it's very you have to write the drivers. But to begin with it's easier to use userspace i2c/smbus/spi to talk to the battery monitor chip directly, but still you need to know the model of the chip and which bus it's connected to.

Comment: Whenever you add a power supply driver to the `power_supply` driver framework, a new directory will show up in  `/sys/class/power_supply`. Whether `POWER_SUPPLY_PROP_CURRENT_NOW` is provided depends on the driver.